# Output all Key-Value data / obtained Environment properties from Spring Cloud Consul

Tags: java, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul

I use Spring Cloud Config with Consul and have a setup for http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-consul/1.2.1.RELEASE/ -> Distributed Configuraion with Consul.

I like to know what environment properties were set by Consul config, how can I inquiry these?

Comment: /env from Spring Boot actuator

Comment: I'd like to do it from code?

Comment: You would have to do something similar to this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/EnvironmentEndpoint.java#L60